# How to set Spring MVC model default values?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, el

I have a Spring MVC project and use JSP as view.

I have such code snippets:

```
<p>${user.name}</p>
```

When user is not null, it renders as expected, but when user is null, my expected rendering is:

```
<p>Anonymous</p>
```

I don't want to set different models in the Controller. Is there any "syntax" for Spring MVC such as:

```
<p>${user.name:default("Anonymous")}</p>
```

or any related?

If any, could you give me a official link for the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`<c:choose>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_choose_tag.htm) from [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for this purpose.

```
<p>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty user}">
            <c:out value="${user.name}" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:out value="Anonymous" />
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</p>
```

Or easier:

```
<p>${not empty user ? user.name : 'Anonymous'}</p>
```

Comment: thanks for both your replay & your elaborative edit. that works for me. however, i still wan't to know about the "${var} syntax", where is the official & fully explanation？

Comment: @marstone for more info you can visit the [StackOverflow EL wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) by accesing this link or hovering the mouse over the [EL] tag in your question and selecting [info] (similar for other tags as JSTL). In the SO wiki, there is enough info to cover the basics and there are links to the official documentation as well.